# For Loop in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm operating a listener in CasperJS that visits a few private websites & waits for certain configurations of data.  Right now, this operates adequately, but not optimally, on a numbered For loop, along these lines:

```
 for (var p = 20000;  p-- > 0;) {

// ... c.900 lines of code ....

}
```

While loops & Do-While loops don't work, due to scoping issues with several instances of Casper.then.

What I'm really looking to do is cron the code over a day timer, to operate between 6am and midnight, something like:

```
// as global variable

function militarytime () {
                var currentTime = new Date();
                var hours = currentTime.getHours();
                var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
                var military = (hours*100)+minutes
                return military;
}

var p = militarytime();

// then within code,

for (t=p; (t=p) && (p>600); t++)
```

This particular way of doing it (and I've tried many) just hangs in CasperJS.

The code has been operating, suboptimally, in a production environment for several weeks, and I've been searching stackoverflow & casperjs/api during that time to no avail.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to assign to `p` inside the conditional of the for loop?

Comment: Yes.  Admittedly an attempt at a hack, as the first statement in a for loop sets the initial condition and is only evaluated once.  I'm trying here to get p to evaluate to [new Date] every time the loop occurs, tying the loop to a current timestamp.

Comment: Ah - I see.  Could you supply any more code to see? It's hard to tell what the for loop is meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a stupid question, but are you firing the run() function?  I've forgotten to include that which caused my program to just hang, generally it's the only reason I've seen for it to hang without error.